# Два блока на всю ширину без float

Tags: css, css3, float

Возможно ли сделать два блока по 50% в ширину, без `float` ,не уменьшая ширины.
То есть, что бы было [вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/m3yn5Lyh/), только без `float`.

```css
.left{
   background: red;
}
.right{
   background: green;
}
div{
   height: 100px;
   width: 50%;
   display: inline-block;
   float: left; 
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 вариант

display: inline-block

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrap{    
    font-size: 0;
}
.wrap > div{
   height: 100px;
   width: 50%;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;  
   font-size: 20px; 
}
.wrap > .left{
   background: red;
}
.wrap > .right{
   background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div
</div>
```

2 вариант

display: table

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrap{    
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    height: 100px;
}
.wrap > div{   
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: top;  
   font-size: 20px; 
}
.wrap > .left{
   background: red;
}
.wrap > .right{
   background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div
</div>
```

3 вариант

display: flex

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrap{        
 display: flex;
    height: 100px;
}
.wrap > div{   
   width: 50%;  
   font-size: 20px; 
}
.wrap > .left{
   background: red;
}
.wrap > .right{
   background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Вариант с `position: absolute;`

```css
.left,
.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute
}
.left {
  background: green;
  left: 0
}
.right {
  background: red;
  right: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Ссылка на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/822f3pxg/).

Comment: Тогда они не будут в одну строку, нужно что бы они были на одном уровне и были по 50%, вы сначала проверьте, а потом отвечайте.

Comment: @Mr_Epic будут, если отступов и обводки не будет.

Comment: Проверять не пробовали? https://jsfiddle.net/m3yn5Lyh/3/

Comment: @Mr_Epic с телефона, немного трудно проверять. Вот еще вариант обойтись без float http://jsfiddle.net/822f3pxg/

Comment: Для вставки демонстрационного кода следует использовать сниппеты.

Answer (score -1):

Всё из-за `font-size`, если его убрать у родителя, то всё нормально.

```css
.left{
background: red;
}
.right{
background: green;
}
.content>div{
font-size: medium;
}
.content{
font-size: 0;
}
.content>div{
height: 100px;
width: 50%;
display: inline-block;
float: left; 
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
```